# Expanding a list to a path

Tags: haskell

I have a list like this:

```
 input = [[1,1], [3,3], [5,5], [7,7]]
```

I want this output:

```
[[[1,1],[3,3]],[[3,3],[5,5]],[[5,5],[7,7]]]
```

(The goal is to have the path made of edges `[1,1]-[3,3], [3,3]-[5,5], [5,5]-[7,7]`... I would not be surprised that this question is a duplicate by the way.)

I'am able to get this output like this:

```
> map (\i -> [input!!i, input!!(i+1)]) [0 .. length input-2]
[[[1,1],[3,3]],[[3,3],[5,5]],[[5,5],[7,7]]]
```

Do you have a cleaner solution? There's surely something cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let xs = [[1,1], [3,3], [5,5], [7,7]] in zipWith (\a b -> [a,b]) xs (tail xs)
-- [[[1,1],[3,3]],[[3,3],[5,5]],[[5,5],[7,7]]]
```

Comment: I always forget that `zip x y` does not require `length x == length y`.

Answer (score 4):

You can `zip` `input` with its tail in order to get a list of tuples:

```
Prelude> zip input $ tail input
[([1,1],[3,3]),([3,3],[5,5]),([5,5],[7,7])]
```

From there, if you need it, you can write a function that makes a list out of each tuple, e.g.

```
tupleToList :: (t, t) -> [t]
tupleToList (x, y) = [x, y]
```

This enables you to map over the zipped list:

```
Prelude> fmap tupleToList $ zip input $ tail input
[[[1,1],[3,3]],[[3,3],[5,5]],[[5,5],[7,7]]]
```

Be aware that `tail` is unsafe, in that it throws an exception if the original list is empty.

Comment: `tail` is unsafe, but `zip xs (tail xs)` is safe. If you want it to be even locally safe (no cross-procedural correctness argument needed), you can replace `tail` with `drop 1`.

Comment: @DanielWagner Indeed it is! I hadn't even realised that. Thank you for pointing that out :)